# How to pass the P101_USERNAME value to another page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How do I do a redirect from the login page passing the P101_USERNAME to another page?

I have a redirect process on my login page based on the password expiry date column on a table if < than redirect to another page to update the password.

Thanks

Comment: May I know which version of apex are you using?

Comment: Assuming that the other page has an item to store the username (i.e. you're redirecting to a page 99 that has a `P99_USERNAME` item), the redirect screen should have the option to pass parameter.  You'd pick `P99_USERNAME` as the destination and `P101_USERNAME` as the source.  Of course, you can also just refer to `P101_USERNAME` from a different page (so long as you haven't cleared the page 101 cache in your redirect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably no need do to that. Why? Because, once you're logged in, `:APP_USER` is set and its value is equal to `P101_USERNAME`, isn't it?

Therefore, wherever you are, reference to `:APP_USER` instead.

If you *must* use `P101_USERNAME`, Justin told you how to do that.